# Why do I get "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" when my activity stops?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a background service that generates bitmap images and sends them to an activity if it is in the foreground. The activity finds the service via binding using `bindService()` and then registers itself using my own `addUpdateCallback()` and `removeUpdateCallback()` calls. These work completely fine when the activity is in the foreground but trigger a `FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION` error immediately after `onStop()` completes when the screen turns off.

There are a lot of similar sounding questions floating around but they all seem to be the result of trying to send something too large. My issue is specifically tied to the activity stopping. Is it possible to keep the binder connection alive while the activity is stopped?